# Typescript: object shouldn't be assignable as it does not contain required keys

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to regroup all my API routes under an enum so I can generate objects based on the params contained in an URL. You can find attached this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/KYOwrgtgBASg9mALsAzlA3gKClA6nAJwGsAzAGzgHcYwQoBeKAIgHpLDSLKUWAud4uSoBJACYsCtHr0kgxTADTY8HIdVoAVVIgbM2qrtJJw4EqXwBGAQwKLMAX0yZEATwAOwKAGU3ZAJaIADxeUMAAHsggomgoiAR+IADmCt4AogAKoRGg0VCx8UkpMKhgZDrhkbn5CYkA2gC6ug0AfLrKIRU5aAAGACToCSTABFAA+vbdygD83lmVPf2Dw1AAMvb9XhnrAyBDIzATyjgzPv5BMCmb6Sm1AHT3xSiliCkr9c1HULyznVFoAOT-T7HNKZX65QFQGZ3B4lMqNb61Lz1YFfKAw26PZ6XFE4b7VJINJyuDxQdI2RBoRinAKBeBIVC3fCCLg0EApf4sf4fHA4FgsKAAPSmxPcnnJBCsEAAalYyGBPIxwBALMsAD55OI1UWkgDiwEQ9OQEqlKDpCGQcy6moKiVajCwvPRAGkoAlvL5aUbgByuc1asrVQRGlY0K7wT1eItdssTRAJlCyTYpWiQMAAG7DerfOOy+XABw6zxaWK6fWGi3AONm70oJkGKhsnm8-lCkWYEi0ADGiD8cDoBGAvisXaryYgNatf1glZQKTB2Wn5e91bpzWaAAoCJXvhcoG5xygcwBKfFapIYZRkA1QEgJOXe3TbhlOHDGEYbrv90tEYAuN10AekoTsel5Ol+IClumcoKroQGmrUv4uCGaC5jBBZOneIAPpWtyDsOo4bkhKTQfmtyIHAXjnokG7HseyiOMog6IGABB0FhOEvoxnYgD2fZ0IkBrMpwja0Bu8ETt8y6Vqutb1iyokgM0oGOlAEGls+lqMPhZAjmOwEoBucnCWobIli8+6HvRfICpQAAW-5+GgEloHKXDAKIbokG6OgQE5KCoFAFhwIgdn7tuHgEL2gXGHAUBWFEQU2FCDhAA) where you can play with the inputs.

I can correctly generate my object to replace my params, however something is wrong when I try to assign an object in a function that accepts a different object. Typescript accept the object when it shouldn't

```ts
enum Routes {
  WorkflowRun = "/workflows/:workflowId/runs/:runId",
  WorkflowRunTest = "/workflows/:foo/runs/:bar",
}

type Split<S extends string, SEP extends string, Result extends string[] = []> = 
  S extends `${infer _}`
  ? S extends `${infer L}${SEP}${infer R}`
    ? Split<R, SEP, [...Result, L]>
    : S extends ''
      ? SEP extends '' ? [...Result] : [S]
      : [...Result, S]
  : string[]

type Parts = Split<Routes.WorkflowRun, '/'>
    // ^? ["", "workflow", ":workflowId", "runs", ":runId"] 

type ParamValue = number | string

type GetRouteParams<Route extends string> = {
    [K in Split<Route, '/'>[number] as K extends `:${infer Param}` ? Param : never]: ParamValue
}

type Test = GetRouteParams<Routes.WorkflowRun>
// { workflowId: string | number; runId: string | number } 

function replaceParams<R extends Routes, P extends GetRouteParams<R>>(route: R, params: P): string {
  let finalRoute = route

  for (const key in params) {
    const value = params[key] as ParamValue
    finalRoute.replace(key, value.toString())
  }

  return finalRoute
}

function getWorkflowRun(params: GetRouteParams<Routes.WorkflowRun>) {
  const route = replaceParams(Routes.WorkflowRunTest, params)
  // why is params allowed if it misses both properties foo and bar ?
}
```

So the question is, how can I fix the `params` assignable in the `replaceParams` function if it's missing both properties required in `{ foo: string; bar: string }`

**Edit**: The post was supposed to get answers about why is this happening, so if you have the answer feel free to comment. I updated the question so it's "how to fix" instead of "why is this happening"

Comment: This is likely a problem with your GetRouteParams types, since `GetRouteParams<Routes.WorkflowRun>` is *assignable* to `GetRouteParams<Routes.WorkflowRunTest>`. https://tsplay.dev/NaEJPN

Comment: I fixed it by removing the need for key remapping: https://tsplay.dev/WzG63w - It seems that key remapping is confusing TypeScript. Might be worth opening an issue about this or consulting an existing one.

Comment: Looks like the problem is that the variance marker for `GetRouteParams` is mistakenly assigned as "independent"/"bivariant"; probably the same underlying issue as [ms/TS#44572](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44572).  The easy workaround is to give explicit variance annotations to make it invariant as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxj9Kw).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for both your solutions! They both seem to work, however I'm intrigued in the "in out" notation in the last one. I'd go "simpler is better" with the Exclude to avoid key remapping, but the second one is worth understanding it

Comment: How do you want me to proceed here? Your question seems to be "why is this happening" and not "how can I work around it".  I'm happy to mention the variance annotation workaround in an answer that primarily serves to explaining the issue with variance, but if you're going to accept a potential "refactor to avoid the problem in the first place" answer from @vr., then I probably won't bother writing it up (and you should [edit] the question to "how can I fix this" and not "why is this happening").

Comment: I edited the post. I will accept the "fix" answer, but for general purpose I believe the reason why it's happening would be very interesting